# Changing or Set Shipping Price on fly from event or observer in Magento

Tags: magento-1.7

I posted this use full code in old blog
 http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/316685/
i want share more info so i continuing in this new post

if you are creating order programmatically and need to add shipping price dynamically then u can use this below code before you call collectTotals function

```
    $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();        


            $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $price=40;

            $address->setShippingAmount($price);
            $address->setBaseShippingAmount($price);
            // Find if our shipping has been included.
            $rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                     ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

            foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
                foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
                    $rate->setPrice($price);
                    $rate->save();

                }
            }
            $address->setCollectShippingRates(false);

            $address->save();
```

this will be used when your placing order out side magento

you use below code for placing order

```
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
    define('PHP_EOL', "\r\n");
    ini_set('memory_limit', '500M');
    $filename = date('Y_m_d_H_i_s').'.log';
    $logPathFile ='var/log/' . 'test.log';
    $handle = fopen($logPathFile, 'w');
    Mage::app();
    $shippingMethod='flatrate_flatrate';
    $paymentMethod='checkmo';
    $quoteid=681;
        if($quoteid){
            $count++;
            try {
            $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quoteid);
            $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
            $customerid=$quote->getCustomerId();
            $customer->load($customerid);
            $quote->assignCustomer($customer);


            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($shippingMethod);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $quote->getShippingAddress()->collectShippingRates();        


            $address = $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $price=40;

            $address->setShippingAmount($price);
            $address->setBaseShippingAmount($price);
            // Find if our shipping has been included.
            $rates = $address->collectShippingRates()
                     ->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

            foreach ($rates as $carrier) {
                foreach ($carrier as $rate) {
                    $rate->setPrice($price);
                    $rate->save();

                }
            }
            $address->setCollectShippingRates(false);

            $address->save();

            $quote->collectTotals(); 
            $quote->save();

            $items = $quote->getAllItems();
            $quote->reserveOrderId();

            $quotePayment = $quote->getPayment(); // Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Payment
            $quotePayment->setMethod($paymentMethod);
            $quote->setPayment($quotePayment);
            $quote->collectTotals();
            $quote->save();

            $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
            $service->submitAll();
            $order = $service->getOrder();

            //$quote->setIsActive(false);
            //$quote->save();
            echo $msg = '#'.$order->getIncrementId().' Order Placed.'.PHP_EOL;

            error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s a') .':'. $msg, 3, $logPathFile);
            $oid=$order->getId();
            $ordernew=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($oid);
            $ordernew->sendNewOrderEmail();
             $historyItem = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
                    ->getUnnotifiedForInstance($ordernew, Mage_Sales_Model_Order::HISTORY_ENTITY_NAME);
            if ($historyItem) {
                $historyItem->setIsCustomerNotified(1);
                $historyItem->save();
            }

        } catch (Exception $e){        
                Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                echo $e->getMessage();
            error_log(date('Y-m-d H:i:s a') .':'. $e->getMessage(), 3, $logPathFile);
        }

        }
```

Comment: Not seeing a question.